# Is there a way to check true/false stability in a discrete transfer/state space model?

Tags: roots, control-theory, linear-control, system-identification, adaptive-control

Assume that we have a discrete transfer function $H(z)$ and a discrete state space model $x(k+1) = Ax(k) + Bu(k)$.

I know how to check the stability, but computing the eigenvalues from the denominator of transfer function $H(z)$ and the state space model, I can just check it's eigenvalues as well.

But what if I only want the answer "Is it stable or not stable?". A boolean answer.

I know that taking the determinant of the time continous state space model matrix $A$ will give me a boolean answer. If the determinant value is negative, then the model is unstable. If the determinant value is positive, then the model is stable.

But in this case, I have only the discrete state space model and the discrete transfer function to use. How can I determine a boolean true/false if those models are stable or not stable?

**Reason why I'm asking**

I'm using recursive least square to estimate a SISO transfer function and I have an idea. If the estimated SISO transfer function is not stable, input some PWM onto the input $u(k)$ because recursive least square needs some stochastic signals to work, as I have heard/read i  the books.

But is that true? I tried to do a simulation if a long constant step response of a second order model with high damping. Here we can see that I don't need "stochastic" output signals to be able to identify the system with recursive least squares. Sure, I know that everything looks perfect in a simulation. But in real world, I would have some noise onto my measurement for sure.

[image]

And the result where, with a 10:th order transfer function.

[image]

If I try to implement heavy random noise.

[image]

We can see that everything went just fine.

[image]

Even when I changed the input signal $u(k)$

[image]

[Source](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/Mataveid) to the library I'm using. I also made a [C-version](https://github.com/DanielMartensson/CControl) too with the same arguments

Comment: "If the determinant value is negative, then the model is unstable. If the determinant value is positive, then the model is stable." It is not true.

Comment: Really. I thought I have had read about that in a book. So there is not way to check stability without checking the eigenvalues? @Arastas

Comment: For continuous time systems you can use the [Hurwitz stability criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routh%E2%80%93Hurwitz_stability_criterion), which apparently also has discrete time counterparts (the Schur–Cohn criterion, the Jury test and the Bistritz test).

Comment: @Kwinvanderveen thanks. But I think solving the roots of the denominator is much easier. But the problem is that I'm going to do this in C language för embedded.